# Convert Pandas column object to date type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in my database, that represents the periods, but this column is made up of objects type data and I need to convert them to date type.

The colume looks something like this

| Period |
| --- |
| 2022/07 |
| 2022/06 |
| ... |
| 1993/02 |
| 1993/01 |

I don't know if the format in which they are presented could cause a problem.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'],format='%Y/%m').dt.date
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three options for handling errors:

```
errors : {'ignore', 'raise', 'coerce'}, default 'raise'
        - If :const:`'raise'`, then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
        - If :const:`'coerce'`, then invalid parsing will be set as :const:`NaT`.
        - If :const:`'ignore'`, then invalid parsing will return the input.
```

You can use `pd.to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Period, format='%Y/%m', errors="coerce").dt.date
```

multiple times with different formats.